# Excel MATCH function returns #N/A when there is a match

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel spread sheet, I have a row containing all dates of the year, and also a list of UK bank holidays. I wish to use conditional formatting to highlight dates that fall on a bank holiday.

When testing if the dates match using a simple comparison `=CX$3=$A$49`, Excel returns `TRUE`.

However, when I use `=MATCH(CX$3, $A$48:$A$56, 0)`, Excel returns an `#N/A` error. My plan is to use `MATCH` as follows in conditional formatting, and apply the condition to all of the dates on the date row ($E$3:$NF$3) -

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(E$3, $A$48:$A$56, 0)))
```

I have tried to [troubleshoot the issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-n-a-error-in-index-match-functions-f91874c9-d30b-4b7a-8a6b-c622764a1992) -

- Both cells are formatted the same (Date) with the same locale (English (United Kingdom)).
- There is no spurious whitespace (proved by the simple comparison returning `True`).
- I have pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> after typing the formula (though I have never needed to do this in any other `INDEX` or `MATCH` function I have used).

What other issues could possibly cause the `MATCH` function to fail?

Comment: You need to select `$E$3:$NF$3` and only then use the correct formula `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(E$3,$A$48:$A$56,0)))` or shorter `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(E$3,$A$48:$A$56,0))`, in conditional formatting. If the ranges are on different worksheets, you need to account for that with e.g. `Sheet1!$E$3:$NF$3`.

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly the same `NOT(MATCH())` formula as I posted, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Select the range `E3:NE3` or `E3:NF3` (not sure, figure it out). On the `Home` tab of the Ribbon, select `Conditional Formatting->Clear Rules->Clear Rules from Selected Cells`. Then select `Conditional Formatting->New Rule->Use formula...` and enter the formula `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(E$3,$A$48:$A$56,0))`. Now select Format to select your formatting and press `OK` as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Try using `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3, $A$48:$A$56, 0))`

You could try this approach:

Select the column/row you want to have your conditional formatting in.

In my example I have all dates from 1/1/2023 - 12/31/2023 (A1:A365) in Column A, and have chosen random dates to represent the 'Holidays' in Column B (B1:B6).

With Column A Selected (Dates):

Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Formula: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B$1:B$6,0))`

This should work even if you have your dates in a row with the following example: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$A$1:$NA$1,0))`

In my row example, Dates are A1:NA:1 and Holidays are A2:D2.

Set your format at the bottom.

When any date in Column A (Dates) match a date in Column B (Holidays) it will format that cell based on the criteria you specify.

This will apply to each cell in column A (Ex: A1, A2, A3...A365).

You can check this by selecting Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > This Worksheet > Applies to

The 'Applies to' sections should be your range you run the formula against (Ex: `=$A$1:$A$365`)